# ios 8 and Swift: call a function in another class from view controller

Tags: swift, ios8

I want to touch a button in ViewController and run a simple function in a custom class. No parameters needed. Code is basically:

```
class MyClass: UIView {
   //init function is here
   //other setup stuff
   ...

func SetFocus() {
//I want to set the camera focus to infinity.
    var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
    var pos: CFloat = 1.0
    captureDevice!.lockForConfiguration(error)
    captureDevice!.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(pos, completionHandler: nil)
    captureDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
}
```

}

```
and in ViewController

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myClass: MyClass!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {

         myClass.SetFocus()

    }
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of (new at Swift) and the app either crashes or the function I'm calling doesn't run. Everything else in MyClass works OK.

Comment: And where is set `myClass`? Does it exists when you call `MyFunction`?

Comment: If it's an `IBOutlet`, have you hooked it up in Storyboard?

Comment: Can we see specific code in myFunction()

Comment: you can also use NSNotificationCenter for this  issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to delete the @IBOutlet from before MyClass.

```
var myClass : MyClass!
```

You can also try this:

```
var myClass : MyClass! = MyClass()
```

From the looks of it, however, everything you are doing in setFocus() in MyClass, can easily be recreated in the ViewController.

Comment: Moving the func + supporting code to the ViewController was the key. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 @IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {

    var ClassViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardID") as! UIViewController
ClassViewController.MyFunction()

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this as-is and with some variations--no success.

Comment: Did you set up the storyboard Id